# Axios is not sending form-data in post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am sending a pdf and title form data from a react frontend to Django REST backend. Im doing this using axios@1.6.7.

**SendForm.js** (form data prints fine before send)

```
            const formDataToSend = new FormData();
            formDataToSend.append('title', formData.title); 
            formDataToSend.append('pdf_file', formData.pdf_file);

            console.log(formDataToSend.get('title'), formDataToSend.get('pdf_file'))

            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')
                },
            }

            const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/posts/create-post/`,
                formDataToSend,
                config 
                );
```

This returns this error from the backend

```
Bad Request: /api/posts/create-post/
[02/Mar/2024 19:15:46] "POST /api/posts/create-post/ HTTP/1.1" 400 28
```

The part I dont understand is, when sending from postman it works fine. Below are the requests, the main difference to me looks like the request Content-Length. Ive tried various other ways of sending it using axios but cant figure it out.

**Broken Axios Request**

```
POST /api/posts/create-post/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 280
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZWvOJOP8DWxLqAIC
Cookie: csrftoken=KpiB3K4gLN4gT3GsnPLfP9eBpOcwJ1Sb; sessionid=hgq77mclr8rynznly95gx40vjaj07cor
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFTOKEN: KpiB3K4gLN4gT3GsnPLfP9eBpOcwJ1Sb
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

**Working Postman Request**

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------998229612431930001760561
X-CSRFToken: E5khHlkBQgTXXhWhosEKtX2LOx1o8z2s
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.3
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: c5e3e2f7-aaeb-4a16-a4da-d6f0e99e691b
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=E5khHlkBQgTXXhWhosEKtX2LOx1o8z2s; sessionid=yvwjf72zx1ymw78uxb4p10dli5pu1wxo
Content-Length: 560891
```

**Axios Configs**

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.credentials = 'same-origin';
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true
export default axios;
```

All other axios requests in my project work fine, although none use FormData(). Ive browsed various forumns that all include it in the post request the same way as I do here and it works for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was listening to the formData using useState, and refreshing by decoupling the state and adding name: value, but for files you have to access the file using the syntax name_of_form_input.files[0].